# Google Recaptcha Promise Timeout

Tags: forms, web, promise, timeout, recaptcha

I implemented Recaptcha V2 into my website onto some forms in there. It worked for half a month, people were able to verify their identity and submit contact data. Unfortunately, it no longer works. Looking at the source in my website results in the website pausing and a debugger opening up. After verifying and submitting the contact form, I get a promise timeout error for recaptcha. I am very confused as to why this worked for half a month and then just stopped when I never changed the code. Google Cloud Platform also has no issues detected.

I tried registering another domain and recreating a key for the recaptcha but it still doesn't work.

Did anyone have a problem like this that they were able to solve?

Console:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Timeout (o)
Promise.then (async)
K @ recaptcha__en.js:226
Promise.then (async)
K @ recaptcha__en.js:226
(anonymous) @ recaptcha__en.js:226
(anonymous) @ recaptcha__en.js:226
(anonymous) @ recaptcha__en.js:113
r.P @ recaptcha__en.js:598
V @ recaptcha__en.js:597
(anonymous) @ recaptcha__en.js:600
e @ recaptcha__en.js:179
```

Comment: This is also happening to me right now

Comment: Me too, right now.

Answer (score 0):

If any one have the same problem in react I removed strict mode and it worked fine for me, I not sure if it going to work for you but give it a try.